# need help debugging assembly code (HCS 12)

Tags: assembly, subroutine, 68hc12

need help debugging, when assembly code goes to my subroutine it is printing out the value of register B instead of the value of register A. Any help is much appreciated.

````
            dc.b    "Type a character"
            dc.b    0    ; using zero terminated strings

         LDS   #ROMStart         ; load stack pointer
         JSR   TermInit         ; needed for Simulator only
LOOP
         LDD   #PROMPT          ; pass the adr of the string
         JSR     printf     ; print the string         
         JSR     getchar     ; call getchar function -result is: character in B
         JSR    putchar
         CMPB           ‘W’     ;COMPARE USER INPUT TO W
         BNE     LOOP       ;
         JSR    WFCN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  WFCN  PSHA
        LDAA    #$3D
        EORA     #$6F
        JSR     out2hex
        PULA
        RTS```
````

Comment: This machine has very limited registers.  Though return values are done in the registers, I believe that parameters are passed on the stack.  Thus, you need to push the value to print onto the stack just before the `JSR putchar`.  Can you push the `B` register onto the stack?

Comment: Thx Chris that’s actually what I ended up doing (pshb) in my subroutine and then clearing it and store the value I wanted to print on to register B.

Comment: That should be `CMPB #'W'` (notice the `#` sign) for immediate mode.  Also, `LDAA` then `EORA` both with immediate operands could be replaced by a single `LDAA` with the XOR result (`LDAA #$52`) as they are both constants and the result can be calculated by the assembler or the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The names of these C functions have always been misleading. `getchar` returns an `int` not `char`, 16 bits. Similarly, `putchar` takes a 16 bit `int` parameter. So it is likely that your specific calling convention uses the double accumulator D (Codewarrior calling convention works like that).

Since D = A + B (and big endian), the results you expect end up in the ls byte, accumulator B.